# Simplification of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I have been given a substitution 
$$x=\frac{y-1}{4-y}$$

And the polynomial is 
$$x^3+x+1=0$$

I am trying to get a polynomial in terms of $y$.

$(\frac{y-1}{4-y})^3+\frac{y-1}{4-y}+1=0$
$(y-1)^3+(y-1)(4-y)^2+(4-y)^3=0$
$y^3-3y²+3y-1+(y-1)(16-8y+y²)+64-16y+4y-y³=0$

I am ending up with $y^3-8y^2+11y+47=0$ which is plain wrong.

Can somebody please point out the mistake?

Comment: Simplification... with respect to **what** ? As it is, $\;x^3+x+1\;$ is as simple as I could expect it to be. Are you trying to achieve something in particular?

Comment: $(4-y)^3 = 64 - 3\cdot 16 y + 3\cdot 4 y^2 - y^3$

Comment: DAMMMMMMMMMMMMNNNNN

Answer (score 1):

You had a mistake when expanding $(4-y)^3$

$$(4-y)^3 =-y^3 + 12y^2 -48y+64$$

But if you just want to solve the quation, why not just solve $x$, and then solve $y$ with the value you get.

Also by the substitution and manipulation, should should keep in mind that $y \ne 4$.